# Are CUDA streams device-associated? And how do I get a stream's device?

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu, cuda-streams

I have a CUDA stream which someone handed to me - a `cudaStream_t` value. The [CUDA Runtime API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/) does not seem to indicate how I can obtain the index of the device with which this stream is associated.

Now, I know that `cudaStream_t` is just a pointer to a driver-level stream structure, but I'm hesitant to delve into the driver too much. Is there an idiomatic way to do this? Or some good reason not to want to do it?

**Edit:** Another aspect to this question is whether the stream really is associated with a device in a way in which the CUDA driver itself can determine that device's identity given the pointed-to structure.

Comment: I am not a CUDA driver expert and I have no practical experience with multi-GPU programming. But I would expect each CUDA stream to be specific to a particular CUDA context. I would also expect each GPU to have its own CUDA context. That would mean a CUDA stream handle is not unique across devices, just unique for each given device. So you may need to pass a pair {device number, stream handle} in the app.

Comment: @njuffa: If a CUDA stream is context-specific, and if a context is device-specific, doesn't that mean a CUDA stream handle _is_ unique across devices? Perhaps I'm not following you...

Comment: A unique stream handle across all devices implies a global "namespace" for stream handles. I do not think that exists. So if you assume two GPUs, each with its own context. The first stream created in each context may get the handle value 1. Somebody passes a stream handle with value 1 to your code. Which device does it belong to? We can't tell.

Comment: @njuffa: `cudaStream_t`s are pointers to structures, not integer handles (like the CUDA device identifiers). What makes you believe these are non-unique handles?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Fair enough.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But it might be the case that even the CUDA driver can't determine which device the stream is associated with, and launches with other devices would fail ungracefully. I mean, it sounds unlikely, but this is really the crux of the question, since if we knew where the CUDA driver can look at, we could look there ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, streams are device-specific.

In CUDA, streams are specific to a context, and contexts are specific to a device.

Now, with the runtime API, you don't "see" contexts - you use just one context per device. But if you consider the driver API - you [have](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__STREAM.html):

```
CUresult cuStreamGetCtx ( CUstream hStream, CUcontext* pctx );
```

`CUstream` and `cudaStream_t` are the same thing - a pointer. So, you can get the context. Then, you set or push that context to be the current context (read about doing that elsewhere), and finally, you use:

```
CUresult cuCtxGetDevice ( CUdevice* device )
```

to get the current context's device.

So, a bit of a hassle, but quite doable.

---

#### My approach to easily determining a stream's device

My workaround for this issue is to have [the (C++'ish) stream wrapper class](https://codedocs.xyz/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/classcuda_1_1stream__t.html) keep (the context handle and) the device ID as member variables of the stream wrapper object, which means that you can write:

```
auto my_device = cuda::device::get(1);
auto my_stream = my_device.create_stream();
assert(my_stream.device() == my_device());
```

and not have to worry about it (+ it won't trigger the extra API calls since, at construction, we know what the current context is and what its device is).

<sub>Note: The above snippet is for a system with at least two CUDA devices, otherwise there is no device with index 1...</sub>

Comment: Just starting with CUDA, and wow, some of the legacy aspects of the API are painful. You would totally expect a stream to be able to tell you what device it is from, but it's just not there. And there's the NppStreamContext, which is what you have to use for streams with NPP, but requires manually initializing like 8 struct fields. Including the device. When I'm holding a stream. Thanks for starting and continuing to work on the library that I would expect NVIDIA to provide :-) .

Comment: Haha, I don't know - is NPP not popular? What do you use if you want to do common manipulations on the GPU (like adding a channel to an image or resizing an image) but aren't comfortable writing your own kernels yet? Unfortunately I don't know anybody at nVidia, but I'll still advocate if any opportunities arise.

Comment: @aggieNick02: Ah, ok, you're doing work on images. Never mind my comment, I was mistaking NPP for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the explicit streams, it is up to the implementation (to the best of my knowledge) there is no API providing this potential query capability to the users; I don't know about the capabilities that the driver can provide for you in this front, however, you can always query the stream.

By using  *cudaStreamQuery*, you can query your targeted stream on your selected device, if it returns *cudaSuccess* or *cudaErrorNotReady* it means that the stream does exist on that device and if it returns *cudaErrorInvalidResourceHandle*, it means that it does not.

Comment: Am I guaranteed to get cudaErrorNotReady for a stream from device n when querying it with device n' selected?

Comment: One of the cudaStreamQuery or cudaErrorNotReady will be returned for sure for the stream that is being queried if that happens to exist for your selected device. The former shows that all operations to the associated stream is complete while the latter shows that it does not; Anyway, either of the two shows that the stream exists. If you get cudaErrorInvalidResourceHandle on a stream it means that the stream doesn't exist at all.

Comment: But can the stream "exist" on two device? To be more concrete, suppose that, internally, a stream value is just an index into its device's array of streams. So, stream 0 will always exist on all devices. Will I get a cudaSucces from all GPUs with that cudaStream_t?

Comment: ping... about my last comment.